# How do I add hyperlink in my textarea in my MVC project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

Hi I am working on ASP.NET MVC project. I have textarea in my view where user will get download link to report.

Currently I have this code in my view page :

```
 @if (ViewData["datalink"] != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(ViewData["datalink"].ToString()))
         {
          <textarea class="jquery_ckeditor" cols="65" id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10">Your report is now available<br />@ViewData["datalink"].ToString()</textarea>
         }
```

For above code output will be like this :

**Your automated report is now available
www.test.com**

But Instead of showing user directly link, I need to provide text with hyperlink like this :

**Your automated report is now available
[DownloadLink](http://www.test.com)**

How can I achieve this??

Comment: You can't. Textareas support text, just text.

Comment: Just convert your `textarea` to `div`  or `span` and apply some styles...

Comment: Why are you using a textarea for fixed content? Just use a `div`, textarea is for allowing input from the user

Comment: @musefan Its not fixed content. Your report is now available is editable. Use can edit that.

Comment: @Ajay: Why would you want the user to edit that? Surely it is a response informing the user of something. Sounds suspect to me ¬_¬

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible to do with a `textarea`. You could use a div construct instead with `contenteditable` property assigned to it:

```
<div contenteditable="true"></div>
```

Which will enable you to place hyperlinks inside + it will give you the same similar functionality as `textarea`.

Answer (score 0):

> Its not fixed content. Your report is now available is editable. User
>   can edit that.

Instead of TextArea, go for Editor like [TinyMCE (with ASP.Net MVC)](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/tinymce-html-text-editior-and-asp-net-mvc-setting-it-up-has-become-easy-with-nuget) that will display the content as you need.